# why we need a user memcached and a group memcached after installing memcached?

Tags: linux

what are this users like

'memcached:x:101:103:Memcached daemon:/var/run/memcached:/sbin/nologin'
'apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin'

use for ?

Answer (score 2):

The 'd' in memcached stands for "daemon"

A daemon, in the Unix world, is a type of program that you expect to provide some service, even when there are no users logged in interactively.

Thus, it needs it's own user and group (for file permissions).

All daemons could run as root, but creating a user for each is more secure.